# Iterating through certain elements of nested list [R]

Tags: r, for-loop, nested-loops, nested-lists

I have a large nested list. Its' structure is similar to the provided dummy data. I would like to loop through this list and apply a certain function only to the elements (vectors) named "seq" while ignoring the other categories. The elements of interest shall be subjected to the another function - a "function_of_interest" in the pseudocode below and the output shall be appended to the new list. Due to the size of my data, I would like to do it in parallel.

Here is the dummy input:

```
x <- list(one = list(one_1 = list(seq = 1:9, start = 1, end = 5), 
    one_2 = list(seq = 2:11, start = 2, end = 6), one_3 = list(
        seq = 3:12, start = 3, end = 7)), two = list(two_1 = list(
    seq = 1:13, start = 8, end = 222), two_2 = list(seq = 1:14, 
    start = 13, end = 54)))
```

And here is one of my attempts which failed:

#loop through the nested list

```
  for (gene in seq_along(genes_list)){
    for (segment in seq_along(genes_list[[gene]])){
      output_list <- c(output_list, foreach::foreach(segment) %dopar% function_of_interest(genes_list[[gene]][[segment]]))
    }
  }
```

Would be glad for help/guidance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this solution which calls `lapply()` on each element of `x` in parallel, and applies `function_of_interest()` to each element of the second-level nested list called `seq`. Note: this requires that each of those lists does in fact have an element named `seq`. You would need to add additional code to test whether this is the case for each list, if there is a possibility that some of them do not have an element called `seq`.

I defined a `function_of_interest()` to test your code.

```
function_of_interest <- function(vec) sum(vec)

output_list <- foreach(i = seq_along(x)) %dopar% {
  lapply(x[[i]], function(x_ij) function_of_interest(x_ij[['seq']]))
}
```

outputs:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$one_1
[1] 45

[[1]]$one_2
[1] 65

[[1]]$one_3
[1] 75


[[2]]
[[2]]$two_1
[1] 91

[[2]]$two_2
[1] 105
```

### Addendum: filter each sublist

If you would like to filter each sublist on a certain condition, you can add a call to `Filter()` before applying `function_of_interest()` within each parallel iteration. In this example we will only apply `function_of_interest()` to the sublists that contain the value `1` within the element named `seq`.

```
output_list <- foreach(i = seq_along(x)) %dopar% {
  x_i_filtered <- Filter(function(x_i) 1 %in% x_i[['seq']], x[[i]])
  lapply(x_i_filtered, function(x_ij) function_of_interest(x_ij[['seq']]))
}
```

outputs:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$one_1
[1] 45


[[2]]
[[2]]$two_1
[1] 91

[[2]]$two_2
[1] 105
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. And what if the function_of_interest would contain more advanced options, for instance filtering based on start value? This is something I am struggling with to apply correctly.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need? I answered your question as best I could based on how you posed it. You may need to ask a new question.

Comment: I do appreciate your answer. However, if you do not mind, I wanted to follow up this thread to avoid multiplying similar questions. So If I would like, for instance, change function_of_interest so it would filter only those sublist, which have 1 inside them, while the rest would be omitted (one_2 and one_3, as they do not have 1 in variable 'seq'. I tried to use Filter() to no avail. Shall I post another question for that?

Comment: I added some more text to the answer to address the additional question. In future you can feel free to go ahead and ask both parts of your question in the initial question.